# Re Order for Guests in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

Is there an option to reorder a guest order?

For example: a customer returns his order, and wants to change the size of the t-shirt. As long as he has an account, i can use the "reorder button" and just replace the product size, but since alot of users checkout as "guests" there is no "reorder" button, so i have to make a new order and copy paste all of their details.

There must be an easier way, i just haven't find it out.

Comment: What about turning off Guest checkout?

Comment: that's not possible because of a google cooperation. it's required to have a guest checkout

Comment: So you want the guest to re-order or you want to reorder for the guest?

Comment: i want to re order for the guest, me as someone who ships the orders from the warehouse

Answer (score 4):

I found this by Googling "magento make guest into user" (I am sure you can Google other options)

The idea is that you can convert a guest user into a real user. Here are a couple of extensions that can accomplish this:

http://www.mlx-store.com/magento-extensions/sales/convert-guest-to-user.html

After the guest is a user than can re-order

<sup>Edit: removed old Magento Connect link</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I have found a easier way.
You can reorder a guest order out of the box.
The button is only not displayed in guest order. I don't know why.

Got to:
*your-store*/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/
- Copy the file view.php

**Create the folder tree in your /local/ like this:**
*your-store*/app/code/**local**/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order
- Paste the file view.php

### Now open the view.php in your /local/. (In line 169 you will find this.)

```
    if ($this->_isAllowedAction('reorder')
        && $this->helper('sales/reorder')->isAllowed($order->getStore())
        && $order->canReorderIgnoreSalable()
    ) {
        $this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Reorder'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getReorderUrl() . '\')',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
    }
```

---

### Now we add a else to the if function and put our reorder button in it.

```
   if ($this->_isAllowedAction('reorder')
        && $this->helper('sales/reorder')->isAllowed($order->getStore())
        && $order->canReorderIgnoreSalable()
    ) {
        $this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Reorder'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getReorderUrl() . '\')',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
      } else {
        $this->_addButton('order_reorder', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Reorder'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getReorderUrl() . '\')',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
    }
```

---

**IMPORTANT: Now flush the cache and then you're done.**
This works for me in Magento 1.9.1.1 - other versions looking maybe a little bit other but the functional should working the same way.